# AWS CloudFormation - Add New Certificate to an existing listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, listener, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

What I have is one platform stack, and possibly multiple web application stacks (each represent one web application).  The platform stack deploys an ECS platform that allows hosting multiple web applications, but doesn't actually have any web applications.  It's just a platform.  Then, each web application stack represents a web application.

One of the HTTPS listeners I have in my platform stack template is this.  Basically I have an HTTPS listener on port 443, and will carry one default certificate (by requirement you will need at least one certificate to create https listener):

```
"BsAlbListenerHttps": {
  "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
  "Properties": {
    "Certificates": [{
      "CertificateArn": {
        "Ref": "BsCertificate1"
      }
    }],
    ...
    "Port": "443",
    "Protocol": "HTTPS"
  }
},
...
```

Now, let's say if I want to create a new web application (eg. www.example.com), I deploy the web application stack, specify some parameters, and obviously, I'll have to make a bunch of new resources.  But at the same time, I will have to modify the current "BsAlbListenerHttps".

I'm able to import the current listener (using Imports and Exports) into my web application stack.  But what I want to do is also add a new certificate for www.example.com to the listener.

I've tried looking around but failed to find any answer.

Does anyone know how to do this?  Your help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to have only one certificate, but have multiple domains that it can be used for?  So rather than adding new certs, you have one cert, and you add domains to it? Would that work?

Comment: No, I actually want to have multiple certificates.  This was made available by AWS just recently, to tie multiple certificates to ALB.  I can do it manually, but not via CloudFormation due to my problem above.

Comment: Ah ok well just add a new certificate to the certificate stack and then update your listener stack with the additional cert id no?

Comment: As there would be some "not so technical doods" doing this, I wanted to make it as automated as possible.

Comment: Sure. Well wrap it in a Jenkins job. Someone needs to enter a list of arns somewhere. Jenkins would hide gory details from a non tech user. The job would output the json and update the stacks via cli

Comment: Jenkins is another dependency here, and hope to avoid to keep the structure as simple as possible.  Wondering if there are other alternatives ;-/

Comment: Can't think of any. The person updating the stack can't update the stack manually? Can they use the cli?

Answer (score 1):

What I do in similar cases, is to use only one certificate for the entire region, and add domains to it as I add apps/listeners that are on different domains.  I also do this per environment, so I have a staging cert and a production cert in 2 different templates. But for each you would define a standalone cert stack, called for example, certificate-production.json, but use the stack name as 'certificate' so that regardless of the environment, the stack reference is consistent:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
  "Description" : "SSL certificates for production V2",

  "Resources" : {
    "Certificate" : {
      "Type": "AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate",
      "Properties": {
        "DomainName": "*.example.com",
        "SubjectAlternativeNames" : [ "*.example2.com","*.someotherdomain.com" ]
      }
    }
  },

  "Outputs": {
    "CertificateId" : {
        "Value" : {"Ref":"Certificate"},
        "Description" : "Certificate ID",
        "Export" : {  "Name" : {"Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-CertificateId" }} 
    }
  }  
}
```

As you can see by using the `SubjectAlternativeNames` property, this certificate will serve 3 wild card domains. This way I can update the domains as I add services, and rerun the stack. The dependent listeners are not changed in anyway - they always refer to the single app certificate in the region.

One caveat: When you update a cert in CloudFormation, it will email all host administrtors on the given domain (hostmaster@example.com etc.). Each domain will get a confirmation email, and each email has to be confirmed again. If all the domains are not confirmed in this way, then the stack will fail to create/update.

Using this technique, I can manage SSL for all my apps without any trouble, while making it easy to add new ssl endpoints for new domains.

I create the certificate stack right after the main VPC stack, so all later stacks can refer to the certificate id defined here via an export.

Comment: Thanks for the advice here.  Though I'd like to bind multiple certificates to the domain actually.  Would you have any suggestions based on that?

Comment: Are you saying you prefer to use one certificate per domain rather than using one cert for all domains?

Comment: Correct.  If you haven't heard of this yet, recently AWS published this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancer-sni/